# How to upload multiple files using multiple buttons - Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I have a code which creates a folder in my google drive and allows user to upload multiple files with file upload as a input.

Script.html

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <base target="_top">
    </head>
    <body>
    <script>
    (function($){
        function floatLabel(inputType){
            $(inputType).each(function(){
                var $this = $(this);
                $this.focus(function(){
                                    $this.next().addClass("active");
                        });
                        $this.blur(function(){
                    if($this.val() === '' ||         $this.val() === 'blank'){
                                $this.next().removeClass();
                            }
                        });
                            });
                }
        floatLabel(".floatLabel");
    })(jQuery);

    jQuery(".mail-btn").on("click touchstart", function () {
        jQuery(this).addClass("fly");
        that = this
        setTimeout(function() {
            jQuery(that).removeClass("fly");
        }, 5400)
    });


      var rootFolderId = 'MYFOLDERID';
            var numUploads = {};
            numUploads.done = 0;
            numUploads.total = 0;
            // Upload the files into a folder in drive
            // This is set to send them all to one folder (specificed in the .gs file)
            function uploadFiles() {
                        //var allFiles = document.getElementById('myFiles').files;
                        var allFiles =                 document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files;
                        var applicantName = document.getElementById('pname').value;
                        if (!applicantName) {
                            window.alert('Missing applicant name!');
                        }
                        var applicantEmail =                 document.getElementById('email').value;
                        if (!applicantEmail) {
                            window.alert('Missing applicant email!');
                        }
                        var folderName = applicantName + ' ' + applicantEmail;
                        if (allFiles.length == 0) {
                            window.alert('No file selected!');
                } else {
                    numUploads.total = allFiles.length;
                    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(r) {
                        // send files after the folder is created...
                        for (var i = 0; i < allFiles.length; i++) {
                            // Send each file at a time
                            uploadFile(allFiles[i], r.folderId);
                        }
                    }).createFolder(rootFolderId, folderName);
                }
            }
            function uploadFile(file, folderId) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function(e) {
                    var content = reader.result;
                    //document.getElementById('files1').innerHTML = 'uploaded '
                            + file.name + '...';
                    //window.alert('uploading ' + file.name + '...');                
                    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(showSuccess)
                    .uploadFile(content, file.name, folderId);
                }
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                //document.getElementById('Assessment-form').reset();
            }


      function showSuccess(e) {
              $('#forminner').hide();
              $('#success').show();
              $('#Assessment-form').trigger("reset");  
             }

    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

form.html

```
    <input type="file" id="myFiles1" class="floatLabel" name="f1" multiple>
    <input type="file" id="myFiles2" class="floatLabel" name="f2" multiple>
```

This allows me to upload multiple files using single file button (only using myFiles1). What I am trying is to upload files in same folder using multiple file buttons(myFiles1 and myFiles2). I tried to change

```
    var allFiles =               document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files;
```

with multiple things such as querySelectorAll but its not working.

Comment: Try this search `[google-apps-script] upload multiple files` on this site,Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: @Alpesh Ahir You want to upload several files to the specific folder on Google Drive. If my understanding is correct, although I'm not sure whether this is the result you want, for example, how about uploading several files by selecting several files using one ``<input type="file" id="myFiles1" class="floatLabel" name="f1" multiple>``? Because you are using ``multiple`` in ``input`` tag.